# html 4.1 action attribute

Tags: html, forms, post, get, action

Can any one please explain me action attribute do take local disk file and  work with get and post method to send and retrieve data back. I want explanation and example both.

Please and thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Try reading a little bit more about HTML forms and make some tutorials, action is sort of the "link" you are going to send the information of the form to. That "link" can then ask for the information that has been passed to it through the form fields.

Searching in google returned quite a few nice places to start with:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/forms.php/

The first link I gave says:

> The data is sent to the page specified in the form's action attribute. The file defined in the action attribute usually does something with the received input

and the second one says:

> HTML form elements rely on action and method attributes to identify where to send the form data for processing (action) and how to process the data (method)

That is a good point of start. Give them a try, read some more and if you are still having trouble, come back for some more help.

Comment: I know this.But any way thanks. I  got the answer. thanks for nice explanation